# keydown event not working if focus is on other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, jquery-events, keydown

I have a form which has multiple textboxes, dropdowns and one checkbox respectively. I want to submit this form If I enter <kbd>S</kbd> button on keyboard.
Checkbox is not a mandatory field, after dropdown next focus goes to checkbox and If I enter <kbd>S</kbd> then the keydown handler is not working.

Following is my code for keydown handler, which I kept in `document.ready()` method:

```
$('#submitBtn').bind('keydown', 's', function() {
    alert("S pressed");
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

When the focus is on submit button then only it work, if I moved focus to other element then it wont. I am new to JQuery/Javascript so do not have idea why it is not working.

I can not provide the complete HTML, following markup is pretty much similar:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="C:/Desktop/test/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#saveBtn').bind('keydown', 's', function() {
                    alert("S pressed :: SaveInfo() function call");
                    //SaveInfo() function call
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div id="saveInfo">
            <ul >
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="30" tabindex = "1" />
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="30" tabindex = "2" />
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox1" value="false" tabindex ="3"/>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <input type="button" name="saveBtn" id="saveBtn" value="Save" tabindex ="4"/>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you still struggling for the solution ? Please share the markup.

Comment: @Mayank : Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: do you handle anything while checkbox change event? do you got solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("body").keydown(function(e) {

 
   
      $('#submitBtn').text("Pressed!");
 if(e.keyCode == 83) {
     $('#submitBtn').text("S Pressed!");
   }
    


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submitBtn" type="button">press here</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but keydown is not working if I have focus on another element like CheckBox. This is my question.

Comment: @milind_db You can remove the reference of `jquery.hotkeys.js` as the above code doesn't use this.

Answer (score 1):

As per your updated question:

You want to trigger the the `form.submit()` event when ever there is 's' pressed from the keyboard

try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mayanksaxena19/me59qcor/),

It server the issue, you are actually binding the keypress event to `#submitBtn` but for targeting complete form you have to target All the DOM elements on the forms.

Simply you can achieve this from select `document` as a selector like following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $(document).bind('keydown', 's', function() {
                    alert("S pressed :: SaveInfo() function call");
                    //SaveInfo() function call
                });
});
```

Hope it serves your issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document.body).bind('keydown', 's', function() {
    alert("S pressed");
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I thin k it is normal. You put the keyDown event on your button this is the reason why the keDown event is only on your button. Try to replace

```
$('#submitBtn').bind('keydown', 's', function() {
   alert("S pressed");
   $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

by

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 's', function() {
   alert("S pressed");
   $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

In this case the keyDown event is on all your page and not only in the button.

Comment: It is working when I do not have focus on the submit button or checkbox or dropbox or textboxes. When I have focus on checkbox it is not working.

Comment: it is not working even when you replace "$('#submitBtn')" by "$(document)" ?

Comment: Yes, It will work definitely. But when I have focus on Checkbox it wont.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this once for the jquery [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method, you can find that the 2nd paramter is for "An object containing data that will be passed to the event handler". So, you can pass anything in that parameter which will be available for every `keydown` event triggered.

Try this code

```
$(document).bind('keydown', '', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 83) {
        $('#myForm').submit();
    }
});
```

Or you can use `.on` also to bind events,

```
$(document).on('keydown', '', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 83) {
        $('#myForm').submit();
    }
});
```

I have specified `83` i.e key ascii code for the `letter 'S'`